# Hibernate - user with enum roles handled with a third table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I am currently working on a user administration for the backend. The users should have different rights. For this I use Hibernate to store the users and roles as manyToMany relationship. I want to achieve the following structure:

[image]

To avoid "free" permissions I would keep the roles as enums in a list per user. Unfortunately, Hibernate does not create an intermediate table for me and I do not know how I can have hibernate create it for me.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @FormParam("username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @FormParam("password")
    private String password;
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private boolean isActive;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name="user_roles")
    @Column(name="role") 
    private Set<Role> roles;

    getters and setters
```

Role.java

```
public enum Role {
    
    ADMIN("admin","Full access"),
    LOGIN("login","Just for login");
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    
    private Role(String role, String description) {
        this.role = role;
        this.description = description;
    }

    getters and setters
```

Ich habe auch versucht eine Zwischentabelle "UserRole" mit einer Klasse zu erreichen, halte ich aber nicht für wirklich richtig bzw. sehr umständlich. Ich glaube das meine Annotationen noch nicht richtig sind und würde mich um einen Tipp freuen.

My setup is hibernate using JPA2.1. My database is a current mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

In an N to M relationship you need an intermediate table, which creates a relationship between both entities.

An entity without an @Join .. (table, column) annotation has no relationship.

To model the entity of this intermediate table, a new entity is not strictly necessary, you should use the @JoinTable annotation as follows:

User entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLE", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROLE")
           })
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Role entity (if you need it)

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLE", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROLE") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER")
           })
private Set<User> users;
```